# Minima.pl implementation of Isotope jQuery library?

Tags: ajax, html, css, jquery-isotope

One thing I don't understand is how did Minima.pl (http://minima.pl/pl) implement that feature within Isotope library where clicking on a thumbnail opens up a bigger gallery of images (a single clickable image, clicking on it makes it cycle through the rest of the images in a gallery) while resorting the Isotope items?

Here is how far I got -> http://tinyurl.com/cr5kzml

Anyone have any ideas on what I'm missing, how do I get this working?

Comment: I've some time left and I'm interessted in helping you. My e-mail is in my signature.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am author of minima.pl website ;).

The part which takes care of repositioning of tiles after enlarging clicked one:

```
$('#mainContent').isotope('reLayout', function(){
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: item.offset().top - 10}, 400);
});
```

It also takes care of scrolling browser window to top of clicked tile.

I am triggering the above action after loading clicked tile content (by AJAX). The trick is to trigger it simultaneously with enlarging the clicked tile.

I will be glad to answer any additional questions.

Comment: I will try and figure out how to load a few of those images in a slideshow later (like the way Systembolaget implemented it on his website) so I wouldn't really need Ajax implementation, but for now I can't figure out how to reLayout the existing items on the page once I expand/load the big image for one of them - I tried integrating that animation bit of yours, but it's just... not happening.

Comment: You have to resize the whole .item element and then apply reLayout, as I quoted above. Just tested it on your website and it worked.

Comment: got it! now, why does the click on the first item push all the other items in a single column, while clicking on the other two items works just fine? and how can I push the maximized item to far right (taking up the last 3 columns) regardless of which item is clicked on?

Comment: Add `masonry: { columnWidth: 180 }` param to your isotope initialisation code and it should work smoothly.

Comment: that kinda worked (why 180 though?)... but now when I click on 3rd item, for example, and then resize the browser to display 4 columns only (or less) the resizing creates some empty spots in the layout...

Answer (score 1):

By click on a thumbnail a ajax function return the same gallery except a bigger replacement for the thumbnail. Then let isotope rearrange the gallery. You can find an example here: http://www.maxmedia.com or http://www.phpdevpad.de (my own site).

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is simple to achieve. Normally, a click on an Isotope .item can, for example, maximise it, another click minimises it. If you want interactivity inside a clicked-on Isotope .item, you simply don't attach the minimisation function to it. Instead, clicking on another Isotope .item minimises the previously selected = maximised item. By keeping track of the previously selected .item, clicks inside the maximised .item won't close it. Basic logic for an example that allows maximising and minimising only by clicking on a "header" zone inside each Isotope .item:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $container = $('#container');

        $container.isotope({
            itemSelector: '.item',
                masonry: {
                columnWidth: 128 // corresponding to .item divs width relationships
                }
        });

        // $container.isotope('shuffle'); // randomise for every new visitor

        $items = $('.item'); // to reference methods on all .item divs later

        $('.header').click(function () { // instead of registering the entire .item div (default use), only its .header div (child div) receives clicks

        var $previousSelected = $('.selected'); // necessary for switching

        if ($(this).parent().hasClass('selected')) { // use $(this).parent() (not $(this)), because the .header div is a child of the .item div

            $(this).parent().removeClass('selected');
            $(this).parent().children('.maximised').hide();
            $(this).parent().children('.minimised').show();

            $items.find('.minimised, .header').removeClass('overlay'); // returns all .minimised divs to previous state after the .item is closed again

            } else {

            $previousSelected.removeClass('selected');
            $previousSelected.children('.minimised').show();
            $previousSelected.children('.maximised').hide();

            $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
            $(this).parent().children('.minimised').hide();
            $(this).parent().children('.maximised').show();

            $items.not('.selected').find('.minimised, .header').addClass('overlay'); // adds .overlay on each .item which is not currently .selected

            }

        $container.isotope('reLayout'); // comment out to mimick old masonry behaviour

        });

    });
```

The actual interactivity inside each Isotope .item can then be coded however you like; hardcoded or dynamic...

Comment: kinda makes sense... question - can I hire you to get that working for me on my site? it's very simple arrangement that I just need to mimic that behavior. If so, how do I contact you?

Comment: Thanks, but for the SO community benefit, I'd rather try to show you the principle in this forum. Maybe tomorrow, I can do a jsbin or jsfiddle for you to explain and update the answer above. Easier to demonstrate with live code one can play with.

Comment: well, for now, I'm trying to figure out how to 1) open up an image gallery section with a few images and 2) have the isotope animation happen while doing that, shuffling smaller thumbnails around the big image gallery. Take a look at the code I'm working with for the time being and let me know if you can figure out what I am doing wrong/missing -> http://tinyurl.com/cr5kzml

Comment: You are giving your Isotope #container ("grid-wrap" in your case) a fixed height in your CSS. When resizing the browser (e.g. Chrome) for the 1st time, your images can't fit such limited height (380px) so it jams Isotope (everything shows in one vertical line). On 2nd and further resizes, it works again. Now, when you want to maximize an .item, there is not enough space for it (380px on your #container) and that throws off your layout. You might want to look at this demo http://tinyurl.com/cvlyhte I set up and nick some desired functionalities from there.

Comment: Umm, I'm not adding that height value isotope container (#grid-wrap) manually - that must be done by isotope JS itself on page load. And even after looking at your example and spending an hour going through it all, implementing a bit by bit in a demo on my end, I can't figure out what is so drastically different in my implementation that I can't even get that reLayout to happen on expand/contract, nor how to fix the image overlap on expand/contract. Ideas?